# Java: Running another program toward the end

Tags: java, joptionpane

I am learning Java, I wrote this very simple class. Everything is fine until I toward the end. Right after the second `showinputDialog`, it continued to another Dialog box from another java file I finished. I am think either I have error in my code, or some setting from my eclipse is off.

```
// Reads in the radius and length of a cylinder and computes volume
// using the formula: area = radius * radius * PI
//                    volume = area * length

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class ComputeVolumeOfCyclinder {
    public static void main(String[] arugs) {
        final double PI = 3.1415;
        String radiusString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                "Enter the radius, \n for example: 15.25");

        String lengthString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                "Enter the length, \n for example: 50.15");

        double radius = Double.parseDouble(radiusString);
        double length = Double.parseDouble(lengthString);

        double area = radius * radius * PI;
        double volume = area * length;

        area = (int)area * 100 / 100.0;
        volume = (int)volume * 100 / 100.0;

        String output = "The area is " + area + "\n The volume is " + volume; 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);
    }
}
```

After I existed Eclipse and try to read it again, it shows this error message.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:989)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:510)
    at ComputeLoanUsingInputDialog.main(ComputeLoanUsingInputDialog.java:14)
```

Update: I don't know why, but now it seems I can't even run this program. Usually I press the green play button and it will run my program. But after restart, it always run the other program (not what I intended to do). I thought my current program should be one of the options?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Better answer, as you are running eclipse instead of `Run As` you may want to click `Debug As` as you see in your picture

[image: debug as]

Then with `step into` (F5) and `step over` (F6)

[image]

After testing, your code works well if you enter correct values but if you cancel `showInputDialog` will return `null` you have to check it, and also check that only numeric values are allowed.

Comment: I am not sure if my settings are messed up, but when I open the debug option, I see "none application"... for some reason it now started to run some of my other java files.

Comment: see view perspective is in debug, try to debug , is great tool to follow execution.

Comment: @George  just right click in the class that you have the main method, and put debug as.. like i show in the pictures

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Javadocs for `Double.parseDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29),

> Throws: NullPointerException - if the string is null

The string `radiusString` or `lengthString` must have been `null` (whichever is line 14).

The method [`showInputDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object%5b%5d,%20java.lang.Object%29) will return `null` if the input was cancelled.  You will need to handle that case.